# Hadoop start-all.sh error:No such file or directory

Tags: bash, hadoop

After I successfully created the name node, I ran into this problem when trying to start name node.
For me it seems as if it's trying to log to a file that does not exist. How could I change my setup to direct the script log to the correct directory?

```
bash-3.2$ start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/bin/../logs/hadoop-Yili-namenode-wifi169-
116.bucknell.edu.out
nice: /usr/local/bin/../bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/bin/../logs/hadoop-Yili-datanode-
wifi169-116.bucknell.edu.out
localhost: nice: /usr/local/bin/../bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/bin/../logs/hadoop-Yili-
secondarynamenode-wifi169-116.bucknell.edu.out
localhost: nice: /usr/local/bin/../bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/bin/../logs/hadoop-Yili-jobtracker-wifi169-
116.bucknell.edu.out
nice: /usr/local/bin/../bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/bin/../logs/hadoop-Yili- 
tasktracker-wifi169-116.bucknell.edu.out
localhost: nice: /usr/local/bin/../bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you don't show us the content of your script, we can't guess it

Comment: This is not because of log file directory, hadoop command itself is missing in the directory /usr/local/bin/hadoop. Make sure this executable hadoop file exists.

Comment: In which directory is your hadoop installed?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `which hadoop`. If this command gives you an output then your HADOOP_HOME has been set in .bashrc file.

If not set then edit .bashrc file in your home directory and add below statements considering your hadoop is installed in `/opt/hadoop`. It may be another location.

```
HADOOP_HOME=/opt/HADOOP
export HADOOP_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

This will help you.