# Hadoop Installation on CentOS 6.4

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed hadoop on 4 nodes (1-master:3-slaves) and formatted name node.
But when i am trying to start services (`$ bin/start-all.sh`) it is denying and throwing a message as bash:

> No such file or directory.

And also i am unable to connect to web browser by giving hostname(or ip address).

May anyone please provide solution to this issue?

Comment: It should tell some file name. Can you post complete error?

Comment: bash: start-all.sh: command not found

Comment: refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796550/hadoop-start-all-sh-errorno-such-file-or-directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318205/error-while-starting-hadoop-daemons